# Why PowerAutomate is unable to map the bucket name grabbed from planner to Status of metrics?

Tags: metrics, power-automate, microsoft-planner

The goal is to extract the bucket name of the task from the planner and map it to Scorecard metrics' Status.

1. Task == Metric
2. Bucket name == Status

While the logic and aftermath evidence in the PowerAutomate Flow shows the bucket name is grabbed correctly for the corresponding task, the scorecard is not reflecting the correct status instead it displays randomly `Completed` or `Done` or `Not Started` for all the tasks ! but the real bucket names are as below

- Blocked/On hold
- In Progress - Review
- Backlog - Prioritized & Scoped
- Completed
- Done

Tried the following:

1. Renamed the Metrics'Status in advance in scorecard directly(manually) so that mapping could be straight forward for PowerAutomate/Flow but its of no use
2. Used `Compose` to gather the bucket name is structural way and then give it to `Create a Goal` Status. Additionally, tried trimming the bucket name within the `Compose` too ! but even then there is no change is the metrics status

Set up of the Flow:

1. [Flow-part above with expressions highlighted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bKf7.png)
2. [Flow-part below with expressions highlighted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBUa7.png)

Missing expression are as follows:

1. Name field of the **Create a Goal** is filled with `items('ForEachTasks')?['title']` which is coming from **Tasks** mapping above
2. Input to **LoopToFindBucket** is `outputs('List_buckets')?['body/value']`
3. **Condition** comparison expression is
   `items('ForEachTasks')?['Status']` *is equal to* `items('LoopToFindBucketName')?['id']`
4. **Update a Goal** Status expression is `outputs('Compose')`

[**Flow run successfully and can see the bucket name is collected correctly in the** `Update a Goal` **status**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FpMaK.png)

[**But in Scorecard, the gathered Status is not displayed**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDJYw.png)

References:
https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Getting-bucket-Name/td-p/171129

## Update

- [Flow result after new mapping with additional Compose](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUtxt.png)
- [Status here correctly shows At Risk which is mapped to Blocked/On hold](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugt7i.png)

But in Scorecard, Although Status has showing bucket names but its not mapping correctly, e.g. this tasks supposed to have `Blocked/On hold`.

[Scorecard metric with the task in observation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jEtz.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you can only set the status to the predefined enum of statuses.

> Flow save failed with code 'OpenApiOperationParameterValidationFailed' and message 'Input parameter 'Goal' validation failed in workflow operation 'Update_a_goal': The API operation 'UpdateGoal' requires the property 'Goal/status' to be set to one of its defined enum values '["Leave unchanged","Not started","On track","At risk","Behind","Overdue","Completed"]' but is set to 'Peanuts'.'.

A possible solution is to create a new Compose with the following:

```json
{
  "In Progress - Implementation": "On track",
  "Bucket name 1": "Not started",
  "Bucket name 2": "At risk"
  // and so on
}
```

Then in your `Update a goal` action, for the `Status`, use this expression:

```js
outputs('MapStatus')?[trim(items('LoopToFindBucketName')?['name'])]
```

Where `MapStatus` is the name of the Compose action with the above Json object mapping dictionary.

Comment: Thanks Sam and now scorecard has real bucket names but seems we should place MapStatus earlier because mapping is not 1-1 please find the updated question with screenshots

Comment: I believe the answer above answered your main question on mapping - please help mark the Answer as Accepted for the benefit of all. Regarding your Update to your question - the mapping clearly works, what happens in the rest of your flow? Do you have any tasks in planner that have multiple buckets?

Comment: Sure Sam, I accepted your answer. After `Update a goal` action, there are no actions. No, each task is in one of the bucket.

Comment: I'm unsure as to why "At risk" isn't coming through to PBI as "Blocked/On hold". I would do a quick debug test in flow and just create a goal with the status set to "At risk" and see if that works. It may be an issue with `/` in the name at PBI side.

Comment: Perhaps Sam, also its not just `/` is causing an issue. Seems `-` is also !

*"In Progress - Implementation": "On track",
  "Backlog - Unprioritized": "Not started",
  "Blocked/On hold": "At risk",
  "Done": "Completed"*


Also, what if we have same mapping for 2 buckets  i.e. in addition to above mapping can we also have these on top? *"In Progress - Review": "On track" and   "Backlog - Prioritized & Scoped": "Not started"*

Comment: Hi @Sam, Earlier, I had renamed the statuses in metrics before running the Flow in order to map the bucket names correctly without using mapstatus action but this didnt work either ! Perhaps thats the reason why mapstatus action wasnt working. Just now, I changed the scorecard itself and the mapping works fine However, in metrics the status displays one of the `default status (At risk, Overdue.....)` and not what I had wished for `bucket names (backlog/onhold, Progress - Implementation ....)` which seems to be not possible. Thanks for your effort and quick help.